# PHPUnit Selenium fail to run phantomjs/ghostdriver test

Tags: php, phpunit

I start grid service - java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.42.1.jar -role hub
I start phantomjs -  phantomjs --webdriver= --webdriver-selenium-grid-hub={hubip/port}

I run phpunit and the output is:
RuntimeException: Invalid response while accessing the Selenium Server at 'http://{hubip/port}/selenium-server/driver/'

```
    org.openqa.grid.common.exception.GridException: Error forwarding the new session The server returned an error : Unknown Command - 
{"headers":
{"Accept":"*/*","Accept-Encoding":"gzip,deflate","Connection":"Keep-Alive","Content-Length":"67","Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8","Host":"","User-Agent":"Apache-HttpClient/4.3.2 (java 1.5)"},
"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"cmd=getNewBrowserSession&amp;1=phantomjs&amp;2=;","url":"/","urlParsed":
{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"","directory":"/","path":"/","relative":"/","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/","queryKey":{},"chunks":[""]}
}
```

I can get firefox to work correctly, so I would assume that the top two commands would work just fine.

Also phantomjs version is 1.9.7